# Equaling Opportunity Close Date to an existing Custom Date Field

Tags: workflow, opportunity, formula-field, closedate

I am trying to create a simple workflow that would make it so that the 'Close Date' in an Opportunity is automatically updated to anything (even if NULL) that is in the Custom Date Field called 'Target Campaign End Date'.

Nothing is working so far so here is my main question - is there any way to submit a new Opportunity with this required field being empty, but being populated due to a workflow when 'Save' is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible to save a record without its required fields. Workaround: Make the other field required too (preferrably) or else save a placeholder date of past which should be ignored by users.

Comment: So there is no way to have the Close Date automatically pre filled upon creation of a new Opportunity?